# Flipping an image horizontally in OpenCVSharp

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv, flip

I recently shifted my project library from Emgu CV to OpenCVSharp. 
The code for flipping the image(using pictureBox) in Emgu CV was:

```
Image<Bgr,Byte> f = _capture.QueryFrame().Flip(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FLIP.HORIZONTAL)
```

I tried using the `Flip(CvArr dst, FlipMode flip_mode)` method in OpenCVSharp, but in vain.
I am no sure what to use for `dst`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Flip method in OpenCVSharp is declared [here](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/blob/10264611fcd41651677eb5da92523d5204ced3fd/src/OpenCvSharp/Modules/core/Mat/Mat_CvMethods.cs).

The Flip method in EmguCV is declared on Line 4162 [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/dd71137d-ff92-2074-9d43-ce62204a5fa2.htm). It sets dst to null (IntPtr.Zero in by its definition).

The original OpenCV documentation on flip is [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=flip#cv2.flip).

For `dst` either specify a `cvArr` (whether `IplImage` or `cvMat` the same size as the `cvArr` you are calling `Flip` on.

This means that the flipped array will be placed in the `cvArr` you pass in as `dst` and your source array `src` in OpenCV and `this` in OpenCVSharp will remain unchanged.

If `dst` is null, then the array will be flipped in place. This means your source array will be changed to be the flipped array.

If you want the same behaviour as you had as before, you can safely call `myImage.Flip(null, FlipMode.Y);` where myImage is your given `IplImage` or `cvMat`.

If you are using an older version OpenCVSharp , then Flip takes the source argument as well, instead of getting it from the calling object. E.g  `Flip(img, null, FlipMode FlipMode.Y);`

Comment: I think what you said in the last statement is enough for me. However, It ain't working. 
My code is `img = img.Flip(null, FlipMode.Y);`, where img is defined as `IplImage`.

Comment: What isn't working ? You shouldn't need the assignment, as passing null modifies the image in place. What version of OpenCVSharp ?

Comment: Thanks! I was being stupid. The assignment wasn't necessary. :)